# Uniswap V1 Calculation of token_amount When Adding Liquidity

Tags: contract-development, uniswap, vyper, defi, bonding-curves

In the [Exchange contract of Uniswap v1](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v1/blob/master/contracts/uniswap_exchange.vy#L55), the `addLiquidity` function involves calculating `token_amount` using the formula

```
token_amount: uint256 = msg.value * token_reserve / eth_reserve + 1
```

Why is there a `+ 1` in the code? Should it not be written as below?

```
token_amount: uint256 = msg.value * token_reserve / eth_reserve
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression `msg.value * token_reserve / eth_reserve` is the floor of the real amount.

So `msg.value * token_reserve / eth_reserve + 1` is most likely intended to be the ceiling of it.

BTW, it's not an ideal way for computing ceiling.

When `msg.value * token_reserve` is divisible by `eth_reserve`, it actually gives 'ceiling plus 1'.

IMO, they should have used `(msg.value * token_reserve - 1) / eth_reserve + 1`.

But the `1` stands for '1 wei', so it's probably not that critical either way...